# I need to create a new DF in Scala and attach rows I already have. How do I do this?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create a df with column headers with strings "v","d","c"

I have 3 rows:

```
in_max =[a,b,c]
out_max = [d,e,f]
weight_max = [g,h]
```

and I want to set up my df so that it looks like this:

```
"v","d", "c"

a,b,"i"

d,f,"o"

g,h, "t"
```

basically the first row, is the first two values from in_max, followed by an "i"
the second row is the first and third values in out_max followed by an "o"
the last two values are the values in weight_max, followed by a "t".

How would I go about doing this in Scala?

Comment: This is not a generic solution but you can create a DF of one row for each case and than union them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simply translate your logic into code:

```scala
val in_max = Seq("a","b","c")
val out_max = Seq("d","e","f")
val weight_max = Seq("g","h")

val df = Seq((in_max(0), in_max(1), "i"),
             (out_max(0), out_max(2), "o"),
             (weight_max(0), weight_max(1), "t"))
     .toDF("v", "d", "c")

df.show
+---+---+---+
|  v|  d|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  i|
|  d|  f|  o|
|  g|  h|  t|
+---+---+---+
```